# Android:Sending data back to MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 3 Activities: Main -> Drink -> DrinkAlcohol 
I move through them in that order, but I want to take the results from DrinkAlcohol and send them to Main.

In DrinkAlcohol I am using *SetResult* and in Main I am using *onActivityResult*. But I am stuck on the DrinkAlcohol page, what am I doing wrong?

DrinkAlcohol XML Button

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="gotoMain"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

DrinkAlcohol gotoMain function:

```
fun gotoMain(view: View){
    val radioButtonID = mRg?.checkedRadioButtonId
    val rb = findViewById<RadioButton>(radioButtonID!!)
    val checkedValue = rb.text.toString().replace("%","").toDouble()
    val asu = mSize*checkedValue/60
    logDrink(asu)

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val returnIntent = this.intent
    returnIntent.putExtra("asu", asu)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
}
```

MainActivity receiving Code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RETURN_DRINK_ACTIVITY) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val asu:Double  = data!!.extras.get("asu").toString().toDouble()
            updateDailyDrinks(asu)
            updateDailyBudget(asu)
            updateWeeklyBudget(asu)
            updateBAC(asu)

        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to get the MainActivity Page which would fire off a set of Toasts, but I actually get nothing I just remain at the DrinkAlcohol Page(Activity).

What am I missing?

Code that calls DrinkAlcohol:

```
fun getDrinkSize(view: View){
    val size: Double = view.getTag().toString().toDouble()
    Toast.makeText(this, "The Drink is $size", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    var intent = Intent(this,DrinkAlcoholActivity::class.java )
    intent.putExtra("size", size)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: put the code when you call "DrinkAlcohol" activity

Comment: I put my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setResult()` does not move you to any other Activities.

Instead of `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)` you should do this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);// If an instance of this Activity already exists, then it will be moved to the front. If an instance does NOT exist, a new instance will be created.
startActivity(intent);
```

And inyour MainActivity `onCreate()` you do

```
Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle !=null){
// get your data here
}
```

You dont need `onActivityResult()`.
The code is in java since i dont know kotlin, sorry :)

Comment: Thank you @So'n I am now back on the main page. but is there any where else I can put my return information that onCreate? I have some calculations to do, and I do *not* want they to occur the first time through.(They can't I do not have the data at that point. (BTW Java is fine, after all Kotlin & Java are brothers)

Comment: as you can see the variable `bundle` is to get the data returned. The first time MainActivity is created this `bundle` will be `null`. We jsut need to check if `bundle!=null`, if its not null then you get the data and show it on your screen etc... if its null you dont have to any thing

Answer (score 1):

I see your error, you need to call `startActivityForResult(intent, request_code)` instead of `startActivity(intent)` in order to receive the response in `onActivityResult` method:

Try with this :

```
fun getDrinkSize(view: View){
    val size: Double = view.getTag().toString().toDouble()
    Toast.makeText(this, "The Drink is $size", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    var intent = Intent(this,DrinkAlcoholActivity::class.java )
    intent.putExtra("size", size)
    startActivityForResult(intent,RETURN_DRINK_ACTIVITY)
}
```

Comment: that only appears to work if DrinkAlcohol returns to the calling activity. I want DrinkAlcohol to return to Main with the result. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: oh ok , so you need a nested result, do the same for your main > startactivityforresult drink -> startactivityforresult -> drinkalcohol